# Asyncio sleep blocking coroutines

Tags: python, multithreading, function, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have this code :

```
import asyncio
import aioconsole

async def imp():
    print("Cool I'm printing")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await imp()

async def console():
    while True:
        comm = await aioconsole.ainput(">>")
        if 'cool' in comm:
            await imp()

async def main():
    console_use = asyncio.create_task(console())
    await console_use

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except AttributeError:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
        loop.close()
```

The problem is that when the code enter to the function `imp()` the `console()` function stops working and I would like to continue using the console for other functions. How can I solve that?

Ps. I tried doing threads, create tasks and nothing is working...

Comment: `await` is a blocking operation. In your code, you await `impl` which in turn awaits `impl`. As this is written, your first call to `impl` will never complete and `console` will be blocked from continuing forever.

Comment: ```await``` is _not_ a blocking operation. ```await``` hands execution back to the event loop. It's just that there is no other task running to swap to.